# how to evaluate implicit (unnamed) variable in for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, implicit, evaluate

The following works fine in JS:

```js
function GetArray() { return ["x","y","z"]; }
var tmp = GetArray();
var s = "";
for (var i in tmp) { s += i+" = "+tmp[i]+"\n"; }
alert(s);
```

Which gives:

> 0 = x
> 1 = y
> 2 = z

Now instead of storing GetArray()'s result in a temporary variable, is there also a way to do this by directly evaluating GetArray in the for (...) part?

I mean like this:

```js
for (var i in GetArray()) { /* ??? */ }
```

Except in this case I don't know how to get element [i] of the array, as there is no explicit variable name to refer to?

Obviously I don't do `GetArray()[i]` as then GetArray is reprocessed every for-step, which is inefficient and its result may even change (not in this simplified example, but in general).

In PHP there is the concept of `foreach(SomeExpression() as $index => $value)`, is there an equivalent in JS?

Comment: If you only care about extra lines of code, then you can always do `for (var i in (tmp = GetArray())) { ... }`

Comment: or you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: the next version of javascript is going to have a for...of that would solve this same problem more elegantly.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Thanks to all, works like a charm! And the topic mentioned by Graeme Wicksted really covers it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])
```

Gives you:

```
function callback(element, index, array) {
    // ...
}
```

BUT the best answer including all caveats can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/675561

Comment: And here are some performance statistics on the different for loops: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/37

Answer (score 2):

You could use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var s = "";
GetArray().forEach(function(value, index) {
    s += index+" = "+value+"\n";
});
```

Or [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var s = GetArray().reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index) {
    return (index == 1 ? getLine(0, previousValue) : previousValue) + getLine(index, currentValue);
});
function getLine(index, value) {
    return index +" = "+value+"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is YES, if you do not use any library such as jQuery or Underscore, you can use forEach:

```
GetArray().forEach(function(value, key) {
    // blabla
});
```

You can find other replacement in Underscore library like:

```
_.each(GetArray(), function(value, key) {
    // blabla
});
```